# Ways to combine jquery-ui Datepicker with inserting text on click.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a table list with many input fields that has the jqueury datpicker in it. Every input field has as class datepicker and a random id number. when clicked in the input field teh datpicker pops up. With a click on he date the dtae gets inserted. So the he datepicker works fine. But now i want to add an image or text link next to the input field, and when i click on the image/text the content on the input field changes into the selected text. But untill now i cannot combine datepicker and this fucntion into one....

example i tried:

```
 <input type="text" id="a11" class="datepicker" name="sterilizationdate_1" value="<?php echo $sterilizationdate_1?>">
    <a href="#" class="CSA" onClick="addTextTag('To sterilization'); return false">CSA</a>
```

and the javascript

```
$('a.CSA').click(function(){
    $('.datepicker').val($('.datepicker').val()+$(this).html());
});
```

I tested this code without the datepicker and it just works fine... why cant i combine the two?

FOUND ANOTHER SOLUTION

[custom text insert in datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/7Wygg/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the `val()` of `input` tag but calling val on `anchor` tag

```
$('a.CSA').click(function(){
    $('.datepicker').val($('.datepicker').prev().val()+$(this).html());
});
```

Comment: this als doesnt work combined with jquery ui dateicker

Comment: i tried the updated answer, the input field stays unchanged when clicked on CSA

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have another problem on how you call the `Datepicker`.

You can try:

```
$('a.CSA').on('click', function(){
    $('.datepicker').val($('.datepicker').prev().val()+$(this).html());
});
```

Instead of:

```
$('a.CSA').click(function(){
    $('.datepicker').val($('.datepicker').prev().val()+$(this).html());
});
```

Please this link [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: nope, doesnt work either, i think the datepicker doesnt allow it in some way

Comment: if i try this code without datepicker it works great... but with datepicker not